# Install python enviroments.txt from SPL_UD_DL

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, virtualenv

How can I install this environment file?

(just a snippet)

```
Package                            Version                  
---------------------------------- -------------------------
absl-py                            0.8.1                    
alabaster                          0.7.11                   
anaconda-client                    1.6.14                   
anaconda-navigator                 1.8.7                    
anaconda-project                   0.8.2                    
appdirs                            1.4.3                    
asn1crypto                         0.24.0                   
astor                              0.8.0                    
astroid                            1.6.5                    
astropy                            3.0.3                    
atomicwrites                       1.1.5                    
attrs                              18.1.0                   
Automat                            0.7.0
```

Full file can be found here https://github.com/lrsoenksen/SPL_UD_DL/tree/main it is an ML project I needed to look into but I can not get it running

I tried pip but it is not in the format of freeze, I tried formatting the file but no success. I'm not super familiar with conda, but I tried using it as well and also did not get any success.

Answer (score 0):

To create a conda environment from a file, you could try the following:

```
conda create --name myenv --file Environment.txt
```

If you would like to install to your current conda environment you can do:

```
conda install —-file Environment.txt
```

More information can be found in the Conda documentation: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

The formatting of the Environment.txt will have to be updated to just have the package name = the version number. You can use the following bash script to do so.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the input file is provided as an argument
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <input_file>"
  exit 1
fi

input_file="$1"
output_file="Environment_formatted.txt"

# Check if the input file exists
if [ ! -f "$input_file" ]; then
  echo "Error: Input file '$input_file' not found."
  exit 1
fi

# Extract all lines from the third line onward and then convert the original file to the desired format
tail -n +3 "$input_file" | awk '{print $1"="$2}' > "$output_file"
```

This will results in your text file sample looking like

```
absl-py=0.8.1
alabaster=0.7.11
anaconda-client=1.6.14
anaconda-navigator=1.8.7
anaconda-project=0.8.2
appdirs=1.4.3
asn1crypto=0.24.0
astor=0.8.0
astroid=1.6.5
astropy=3.0.3
atomicwrites=1.1.5
attrs=18.1.0
Automat=0.7.0
```

Comment: CondaValueError: could not parse 'Package                            Version' in: Environment.txt

Comment: even if I remove the first lines 

CondaValueError: could not parse 'absl-py                            0.8.1' in: Environment.txt

Comment: There should be two equal signs. For example `absl-py==0.8.1`.